# Is there a way to fetch all directories and files matching a pattern with wildcards recursively in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, filesystems

I am looking for a library that allows me to take something similar to this:

```
./*
./*/*.*
./**
./**/*.*
./*.cs
./folder1/*.png
```

Then i would need to pass it to a method which scans the filesystem and returns these paths:

```
C:\folder1, C:\folder2, C:\folder3
C:\folder1\file.cs,C:\folder1\test.dll,[...], C:\folder2\image.png, [...]
C:\folder1, C:\folder1\results, C:\folder2, [...]
C:\file1.cs, C:\file2.cs, C:\file3.cs
C:\folder1\image1.png, C:\folder1\image2.png, [...]
```

I am aware that `Directory.GetFiles()` and `Directory.GetDirectories` exist and that they accept a filter, but i need one method that does this recursively and flexibly and returns a set of absolute paths.

Comment: [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-6.0#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_) is already recursive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a library like [Glob library](https://github.com/kthompson/glob) which unlike .net [file globbing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/file-globbing) does folders with wild cards.

```
var folder = @"Your path goes here";

string[] folderPatterns = { "**/bin", "**/obj" };
string[] filePatterns = { "**/*cs"};

var results = new List<string>();

foreach (var pattern in folderPatterns)
{
    results.AddRange(Glob.Directories(folder, pattern).ToArray());
}

foreach (var pattern in filePatterns)
{
    results.AddRange(Glob.Files(folder, pattern).ToArray());
}
```